# How to update a Textview found in an Activity form other class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textupdate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textupdate = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    MediaPlayerclass mpclass = MediaPlayerclass(getApplicationContext());
    mpclass.MediaPlayer_Start(R.raw.track1);

}

public void mUpdateCountv() {

    System.out.println("textupdate "textupdate); //Returns null from MediaPlayerclass
    textupdate.setText("MpCompleted");

}
```

Mediaplayerclass

```
public class MediaPlayerclass {
    private Context mContext = null;
    private int mResId = 0;
    MainActivity mainactivity;
    public MediaPlayer mCurrentPlayer = null;

public MediaPlayerclass(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mainactivity = new MainActivity();
}

public void MediaPlayer_Start(int resId) {
    this.mResId = resId;
    mCurrentPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mResId);
    mCurrentPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
    mCurrentPlayer.start();
}

public MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mCurrentPlayer.release();

        //Textview Update
        mainactivity.mUpdateCountv();
    }
};
```

Log

> 05-01 13:00:48.258: E/AndroidRuntime(5599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 05-01 13:00:48.258: E/AndroidRuntime(5599): Process:
>   com.example.media, PID: 5599
>
> 05-01 13:00:48.258: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>
> 05-01 13:00:48.258: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):   at
>   com.example.media.MainActivity.mUpdateCountv(MainActivity.java:665)
>
> 05-01 13:00:48.258: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):   at
>   com.example.media.MediaPlayerclass$1.onCompletion(MediaPlayerclass.java:41)
>
> 05-01 13:00:48.258: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):   at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2538)

When i call the `mUpdateCountv` method from mediaplayerclass `textupdate` is always null, so i cant able to update my textview from `MediaPlayerclass` class. is there anything wrong with my code thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MediaPlayer class constructor do:

```
mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
```

And in your MainActivity pass `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

You're creating a new Activity, but you need your old instance. You can use this as the Context object (because Activity is a child class of Context), and cast it to MainActivity if you need to call the update method.

Answer (score 1):

One alternate, declare your textview as static like this:

```
static TextView textupdate;
```

and then you can directly update textview in Mediaplayerclass like this:

```
MainActivity.textupdate.setText("MpCompleted");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,I think declaring Widget as static is bad idea.